# PHP PDO применение html тегов в подготовленных запросах?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Использую PHP PDO и следующий запрос:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare("UPDATE item SET description = :desc WHERE id = :item_id");
$statement->execute([':desc' => 'Например число 3<sup>2</sup> называют как три во второй степени, или три в квадрате.', ':item_id' => 26]);
```

При выполнении данного запроса происходит ошибка:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\x81<sup>...' for column 'description' at row 1
```

Я понял что проблема в следующем, в подготовленном запросе почему-то учитываются html теги, в итоге `3<sup>2</sup>` преобразуется в 3<sup>2</sup>, именно из-за этого и происходит ошибка, при вставке данных напрямую без PDO запрос выполняется успешно. Почему в PDO html теги учитываются, это же просто текст (пусть и html), тут же нет какого-то инструмента как в браузере, который преобразует теги, как этого можно избежать? Также нужно чтобы в базе хранились именно теги html, а не спецсимволы, чтобы при выводе на странице браузера они учитывались, т.е. например функция `htmlspecialchars` здесь не подходит.

P.S. при преобразовании 3<sup>2</sup> происходит ошибка связанная с кодировкой, т.к. в utf-8 как я понимаю нет такого символа.

Comment: Я боюсь все совсем не так. Он вам пишет, что некорректное значение `\x81<sup>`. Как видите `<sup>` ни во что не преобразовывался. Зато перед ним стоит символ с кодом \x81, а не 3. То что вы в тексте программы написали как `3`, ей не является, а некий однобайтный символ со старшим битом, которого в utf-8 быть не может. Если вы откуда то получили строку в другой кодировке то сначала перекодируйте ее в utf-8. Что касается приведенного вами примера, то сотрите в тем эту "тройку" и еще раз введите ее с клавиатуры

Comment: Я сейчас попробовал запустить этот же запрос, но предварительно к данным применил функцию `htmlspecialchars`, которая просто преобразовывает все теги html в спецсимволы, и запрос выполнился успешно. Не значит ли это что дело в html тегах?

Comment: Что примечательно, скрипт построен таким образом что копирует данные из одного поля другой записи в это же поля, при этом и в бд, и в php используется кодировка utf-8.

Comment: не значит. вы попробовали 3 удалить и ввести заново с клавиатуры ?

Comment: Да, попробовал, это сработало. Но как-то странно, т.к. я копирую значение из этого же столбца в бд.

Comment: Значит у вас в БД сейчас лежит строка байт, не являющихся UTF-8. MySQL ничего не может с этим поделать и отдает ее вам как есть. А вот обратно не принимает, потому что на сессии стоит правильная кодировка и он производит контроль вносимых данных

Comment: Т.е. в поле со сравнением utf8mb4_unicode_ci мог проникнуть не UTF-8 символ? Не должно ли это вызвать ошибку при вставке данных?

Comment: MySQL штука загадочная. если во время вставки на соединении стояла неверная кодировка то он вполне мог это сделать. Но это просто догадки. Не могу сказать как у вас в поле оказался недопустимый символ. Но вы сами экспериментально подтвердили что он там есть. И что самое печальное, если остальные символы корректны, то никакие перекодировки не позволят вылечить символ. Ради прикола можете попробовать сделать iconv в cp1251 и обратно и посмотреть что получится. По идее на каком от из этапов все спецсимолы должны уйти